# Error: Unexpected token punc «)», expected punc «,» while minifying angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

I am trying to minify my app.js code (tried several online tools). But I get the error mentioned in the question. Here's my code:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('LazyApp', []);
    app.directive('lazyLoad', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope : {},
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(element[0].querySelectorAll("img[data-src]"));
                var videos = Array.prototype.slice.call(element[0].querySelectorAll("iframe[data-src]"));
            }
        }
    })
}])();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the '[' before you function tag is the problem ..

Comment: @KishoreSahas not quite but the braces and square brackets definitely seem mismatched

Comment: I just realised I didn't add '$window' just before my function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this

```
(function() {
    angular.module('LazyApp', [])
    .directive('lazyLoad', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope : {},
            link: function(scope, element) {
                var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(element[0].querySelectorAll("img[data-src]"));
                var videos = Array.prototype.slice.call(element[0].querySelectorAll("iframe[data-src]"));
            }
        };
    }])
})();
```

You had the closing square bracket for your directive constructor in the wrong place.